# How to execute powershell script using AzureCLI?

Tags: azure, powershell, azure-cli2

I am trying to execute a powershell script to create resources on the Azure infrastructure. I have installed Azure CLI on my machine and followed all the steps to login using az login command. I have also setup my subscription using az account set --subscription "My Demos" command.

Now I want to execute the powershell script using this setup.

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please add the word `powershell` before the powershell scripts when running in azure cli.

Like below:

```
powershell Get-AzVM -ResourceGroupName "xxx" -Name "xxx" -Status
```

[image]